# How do I interpret an augmented dickey-fuller test with 3 lags? [Econometrics]

Tags: regression, econometrics, stata

TLDR: I have found my variable is stationary using the augmented dickey-fuller test, but this took 3 lags to remove serial correlation. How do I interpret this, does this mean I need 3 lags of the variable in my final regression to ensure stationary?

My steps and subsequent problem (code is Stata):

I have a variable that I am testing for stationarity. I use 'tsline variable' and identify that the variable has a constant and time trend.

I use: 'reg D.variable L.variable time estat bgodfrey lags(1/3) nomiss0'

And I find that the variable is serially correlated meaning I need to augment the Dickey-Fuller test. I subsequently try and determine how many lags I need:

'reg D.variable L.variable L2.variable time'
'estat bgodfrey lags(1/3) nomiss0'

Repeating the process until I no longer have serial correlation. I find that I need to have 3 lags to remove sc.
'reg D.variable L.variable L2.variable L3.variable time'

I then proceed with the Augmented Dickey Fuller Test:
'dfuller variable, lags(3) trend'

Stata outputs results that suggest that it is stationary. My problem is, how do I interpret this? Does that mean that the variable is straight-up stationery? Or does it mean that it is only stationary provided I include 3 lags of the variable?

I have tried differencing my variable and I go through a similar process, still unsure how to interpret the result. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi @Thomas Spencer. You require a white noise stationary error for your process to be stationary. Otherwise, you will introduce non-stationarity into your process. Recall here, that stationarity is another way of saying your process has predictable properties; whereas if it is estimated with a persistent error - it is not predictable.

Comment: I appreciate the concept of stationarity, but I am still no clearer to understanding my question. What is the interpretation?

Comment: Hi @Thomas Spencer. Peculiar tone to take with someone trying to help you. But nevertheless, I provided the interpretation in my comment. Namely, you require your error to be white noise for your process to be stationary. This does not make your process stationary; but it is a pre-requisite.